# Assigning value to read-only member - C++

Tags: c++, readonly, protected

How would I go about making an ElectricPump and assigning the value "rate" within that object. I get the following error with my current code:

```
../src/Boat.cpp:144:7: error: assignment of read-only member 'Pump::rate'
```

Below is my class declaration:

```
class Pump
{
protected:
    Pump(float rate);
    virtual void pump(Boat &) = 0;
    const float rate;
};

class ElectricPump : public Pump
{
public:
    ElectricPump();
    virtual void pump(Boat &);
};
```

Implementation:

```
Pump::Pump(float r) : rate(r){}

ElectricPump::ElectricPump(){
    rate = 5.0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `const` is for?? Also that can be fixed using the bas class constructor in the member initializer list: `ElectricPump::ElectricPump() : Pump(5.0) {`

Comment: Worth a quick reminder that all member variables and base classes are constructed before entering the body of the constructor. You should have gotten another error message saying that `Pump` could not be constructed because of the missing default constructor.

Comment: Closing this question as 'unclear what you're asking' is ridiculous. This is a perfectly fine question, and any reasonable C++ programmer is going to understand exactly what the OP was asking almost immediately. My main concern would be that I strongly suspect it's a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Members declared as const cannot be assigned, only initialized, e.g. in the course of an initializer list of a constructor. So as a subclass cannot initialize data members of its superclass, you'll have to "call" the superclass' constructor:

```
ElectricPump::ElectricPump() : Pump(5.0) { }
```

Comment: @SoupSeeker - It's considered polite to click on the little green check for the answer that answers your question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Members marked as `const` must have a value assigned before the construction of the object. On top of this, you must either declare a default constructor for `Pump` or explicitly call the defined constructor in the `ElectricPump` class.

Note that the initializer list is ran before construction of the object, so `const` members can be set in that. To fix your issue, use this:

```
ElectricPump::ElectricPump()
    : Pump(5.0)
{ }
```

This will call the constructor for `Pump` with your passed in value before construction of `ElectricPump`. I highly suggest reading up on [initializer lists](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) and how they are used.